# Rails-4 Devise + CanCan not hiding edit and destroy links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I am using CanCan and Devise, but the devise users is managed via custom UsersController. I want only a logged_in user to see the **edit** and **destroy** links. But right now depend on what is passed to the ability class, it either hids the **edit** and **destroy** links for all users including logged_in user or it exposes the **edit** and **destroy** links of all users to **any signed_in user**, hence they can edit any user account event if it wasn't theirs.

users/index.html.erb

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
       <div><%= user.email %></div>

       <% if user_signed_in? %> 

         <% if can? :update, user %>
           <div class=" btn "><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) %> </div>
         <% end %>

         <% if can? :destroy, user %>
          <div class="btn btn-danger"><%= link_to 'Remove', user, method: :delete, data: {confirmation: 'Are you sure'} %></div>
         <% end %>

      <div><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %> </div>

      <% end %> <!-- closes user_signed_in? -->
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

The ability class

```
 class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
     #to ensure user object is not nil when no user object is passed in
     user ||= User.new    

     can :manage, User do |user|

     #this exposes the destroy and edit links for all users including users not yet signed_in 

      #user.id == user.id

     #this hide the destroy and edit links for all users including signed_in user
      user == :user_id 
    end
  end
end
```

**Please Note that I added the Userscontroller below the 2nd screenshot**

screen shot 1 shows that if  **user.id == user.id** in the **ability class** is uncommented, it exposes the **destroy** and **edit** links for all users including users **not yet signed_in** and the **signed_in** user can edit accounts **not belonging** to him. In the screenshot, the real signed_in user's email is **a@test.com** but you can see that he has access to the **edit** and **destroy** links for the user that is not signed_in which is **b@test.com**
   [image]

Screen shot 2, is what we get when we uncomment **user == :user_id** in the ability class. The edit and destroy links are hidden even from the signed_in user.
[image]

Shortened version of the User controller

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
     before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:new, :create]
     load_and_authorize_resource , only: [:index, :edit, :destroy]

     respond_to :html, :json

    def index
      @users = User.all
      respond_with @users
    end

    def edit
     #@user = User.find(params[:id])
     #respond_with @user
    end

    def destroy
      @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path, {notice: 'A user was removed'}
    end

    private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

  end
```

The sessions controller

```
 class UsersSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    respond_to :html, :json

    def create
      super
      if signed_in?(resource) 

        #call the code to transfer guest cart to signed_in user
        load_current_cart
      end
    end
  end
```

**fixed by @gotva's answer below. So with: **can :manage, User, :id => user.id** only **a@test.com** who is the the logged_in user sees the **edit** and **destroy** links. The new screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define ability through Hash (not Block)
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions

```
can :manage, User, :id => user.id
```

Comment: Thanks. This was what I tried first yesterday and it didn't work and it did not throw any error. I decided to try it again since you posted it as answer but it now throws the error: **NoMethodError in Users#index** and **undefined method `user_id' for #<User:0x00000002f4e410>**. Though the user is signed in.

Answer (score 0):

In your ability.rb: did you try just:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user
# you can here try some condition if you have multi user types
can [:new, :create], :all
```

Comment: Thanks for suggested answer, I have tried it and it did not resolve the problem.